# Error: warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout. [I'm in the master branch]

Tags: git

I'm a Git newbie, and I got the following error.

I've already searched for it, and I've found that: the others when they had this error, they where in an other branch than master, and that's not my situation.

When I do "git branch" on terminal, I only see the master (not another branch).

So what should I do? I've already tried to delete everything and restart but well ._.

Here what I've already tried to do this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:figarocms/test.git
git ls-remote --heads origin
git clone git@github.com:figarocms/test.git --branch master 
git clone git@github.com:figarocms/test.git --branch master -b master --single-branch
```

Hope you can help me, and sorry for my bad english.
Thank you ~ ~

Comment: What operation did you actually do to generate this error?  I'm not sure you suggested fix is the best course of action here.

Comment: Are you sure that your remote repo has any commits at all?  git can be a little weird about the state of a repo before the first commit is created

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing (or are experimenting to learn), avoid both the `--single-branch` and `--depth` (which implies `--single-branch`) options (these *may* have something to do with the actual problem, but I can't be sure from what you have posted). Please also see the StackOverflow guide at [mcve].

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen On my Terminal I've just done: `git init` `git clone git@git...`

Comment: Oh dear...that doesn't sound right.  If you cloned your current `master` branch from a remote repository, then `git init` almost certainly is _not_ what you want to be doing right now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh I see!
I don't need to do a `git init` before `git clone _ ` :o
@MarkAdelsberger I think I did, but I don't know what they weren't loaded, when I tryed again it worked, I don't understand w_w

Comment: If you're creating your own repo from scratch then maybe you would do `git init`.  Otherwise, just install Git, point it somewhere (e.g. GitHub or Bitbucket), copy the clone URL and do `git clone some_url`.  Let Git worry about the internals.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the problem

```
git branch (if nothing comes out, even master, do: git branch -a)
git checkout develop
```

With git branch -a, i've loaded 3 remotes/origin/_ (develop, jwt and reset_pwd)